# SQL Return Comma Separated List - specified trim length is greater than current LOB value's length

Tags: sql, oracle, string-aggregation

I'm currently using Oracle XE 11gR2. I want to be able to take in around 20,000 rows of data from a table and combine it into one comma separated string.

My code:

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT("A", colName) ORDER BY 1).getClobVal(),'<A>',''),'</A>',',')
FROM TABLE_DATA
```

I've already tested this code with a table that has approximately 1,000 rows and it works perfectly. But with my larger table, I always get this error:

> ORA-22926: specified trim length is greater than current LOB value's length

Comment: Not sure - I don't have your table, but I created a copy of `SCOTT.EMP` and cloned each row 1,000 times; your query works fine on it, aggregating 14,000 names into a single comma-separated string of length 84,000+. What is the data type of `colName`? Also, the way you are creating the comma-separated `CLOB` is a bit unusual; the one I've seen more often (and it's worth trying out to see if you can learn anything from it, regarding your issue) is `ltrim(XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(a, ',' || colName) ORDER BY 1).extract('//text()').getclobval(), ',')`

Comment: Oh, one more thing... I tried on Oracle 12.2; but I don't think that should make a difference.